# Generating a custom ItemGroup with custom settings in .vxcproj using CMake or change midl attributes

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcxproj

I'm trying to port a project from `Visual Studio 2013` to `cmake` and I'm facing a problem with Midl compiler.

The original project has a `project.vcxproj` file which have kind of:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
<Midl Include="project.idl">
      <TypeLibraryName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">.\Debug/project.tlb</TypeLibraryName>
      <HeaderFileName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">project_Interface.h</HeaderFileName>
      <DllDataFileName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">dlldata.c</DllDataFileName>
      <InterfaceIdentifierFileName Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">project_Interface.c</InterfaceIdentifierFileName>
      <MkTypLibCompatible Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</MkTypLibCompatible>
</Midl>
</ItemGroup>
```

After this `ItemGroup` there is other `ItemGroup` with the Source code `ClInclude`, etc.

My problem is that with kind of this `cmake` code:

```
set(MIDL_FILE
   project.idl
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${MIDL_FILE})
```

This generate a `project.vcxproj` which had a unique `ItemGroup` with something like:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ClInclude Include="file.h" />
  <Midl Include="project.idl" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here the problem is that with this project the `project_Interface.h` is not generated. I have add manually the snippet that I shared, that is add the other `ItemGroup` and it is able to invoke the `midl compiler` and generates the files.

I saw that the `midl` is invoked. However, the settings seems to be taken from this:

```xml
<Midl>
  <OutputDirectory>$(ProjectDir)/$(IntDir)</OutputDirectory>
  <HeaderFileName>%(Filename).h</HeaderFileName>
  <TypeLibraryName>%(Filename).tlb</TypeLibraryName>
  <InterfaceIdentifierFileName>%(Filename)_i.c</InterfaceIdentifierFileName>
  <ProxyFileName>%(Filename)_p.c</ProxyFileName>
</Midl>
```

This generated the `project.h`, is there any way of change these attributes?

I have tried with [VS_GLOBAL_<variable>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_variable.html) and I saw that this entry is generated in `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">`. However this is no used in `midl` compiler call.

Here the thing is:

1. Is there any way of change the midl settings?
2. Is there any way of define a custom `ItemGroup` with specific settings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `VS_SETTINGS` seems to work as I expected. I add set_property(SOURCE project.idl PROPERTY VS_SETTINGS "KEY=value")